# Time Series Prediction with Keras - Error in Model Values

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

As recommended in my last post, I rewrote the script I am using to do time series analysis using lib KERAS, but getting the following output in the model.

In recurrent networks, the input shape should be like (batch size, time steps, input features).

**OUTPUT**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rnrs.py", line 114, in <module>
    model = train_model(get_model(), X_train, Y_train, (X_dev, Y_dev), [plot_losses])
  File "rnrs.py", line 111, in train_model
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=200, batch_size=1024, validation_data=validation, callbacks=callbacks, shuffle=False)
  File "C:\Users\luis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1213, in fit
    self._make_train_function()
  File "C:\Users\luis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 316, in _make_train_function
    loss=self.total_loss)
  File "C:\Users\luis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\luis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 75, in symbolic_fn_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\luis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers.py", line 543, in get_updates
    p_t = p - lr_t * m_t / (K.sqrt(v_t) + self.epsilon)
  File "C:\Users\luis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\math_ops.py", line 903, in binary_op_wrapper
    y, dtype_hint=x.dtype.base_dtype, name="y")
  File "C:\Users\luis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 1242, in convert_to_tensor_v2
    as_ref=False)
  File "C:\Users\luis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 1296, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "C:\Users\luis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 286, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\luis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 227, in constant
    allow_broadcast=True)
  File "C:\Users\luis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 265, in _constant_impl
    allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
  File "C:\Users\luis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\tensor_util.py", line 437, in make_tensor_proto
    raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
ValueError: None values not supported.
```

**SCRIPT**

```
import pandas as pd

def load_dataset():
    ds = pd.read_csv('hour.csv')
    ds['dteday'] = pd.to_datetime(ds['dteday'])
    return ds

def one_hot_encoding(df, field):
    one_hot_encoded = pd.get_dummies(df[field])
    return  pd.concat([df.drop(field, axis=1), one_hot_encoded], axis=1)

def preprocess_dataset(df):

    df_reduced = df[['dteday', 'cnt', 'season','yr', 'mnth','hr', 'holiday', 'weekday', 'workingday', 'weathersit', 'temp', 'atemp', 'hum', 'windspeed']]
    df_reduced = one_hot_encoding(df_reduced, 'season')
    df_reduced = one_hot_encoding(df_reduced, 'mnth')
    df_reduced = one_hot_encoding(df_reduced, 'hr')
    df_reduced = one_hot_encoding(df_reduced, 'weekday')
    df_reduced = one_hot_encoding(df_reduced, 'weathersit')

    return df_reduced

dataset = load_dataset()
dataset = preprocess_dataset(dataset)

from datetime import datetime

def filter_by_date(ds, start_date, end_date):

    start_date_parsed = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d") 
    start_end_parsed = datetime.strptime(end_date, "%Y-%m-%d")

    return ds[(ds['dteday'] >= start_date_parsed) & (ds['dteday'] <= start_end_parsed)]

train = filter_by_date(dataset, '2011-01-01', '2012-10-31')
dev = filter_by_date(dataset, '2012-11-01', '2012-11-30')
val = filter_by_date(dataset, '2012-12-01', '2012-12-31')

import numpy as np

def reshape_dataset(ds):

    Y = ds['cnt'].values

    ds_values = ds.drop(['dteday', 'cnt'], axis=1).values
    X = np.reshape(ds_values, (ds_values.shape[0], 1, ds_values.shape[1]))

    return X, Y

X_train, Y_train = reshape_dataset(train)
X_dev, Y_dev = reshape_dataset(dev)
X_val, Y_val = reshape_dataset(val)

import keras
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import clear_output

class PlotLosses(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.i = 0
        self.x = []
        self.losses = []
        self.val_losses = []

        self.fig = plt.figure()        
        self.logs = []

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):

        self.logs.append(logs)
        self.x.append(self.i)
        self.losses.append(logs.get('loss'))
        self.val_losses.append(logs.get('val_loss'))
        self.i += 1

        clear_output(wait=True)
        plt.plot(self.x, self.losses, label="loss")
        plt.plot(self.x, self.val_losses, label="val_loss")
        plt.legend()
        plt.show()

plot_losses = PlotLosses()

from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, LSTM, Dropout

def get_model():

    input = Input(shape=(1, 58))
    x = LSTM(200)(input)
    x = Dropout(.5)(x)
    activation = Dense(1, activation='linear')(x)
    model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=activation)

    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01,
                                      beta_1=0.9,
                                      beta_2=0.999,
                                      epsilon=None,
                                      decay=0.001,
                                      amsgrad=False)

    model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer=optimizer)
    model.summary()

    return model

get_model()

def train_model(model, X_train, Y_train, validation, callbacks):

    model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=200, batch_size=1024, validation_data=validation, callbacks=callbacks, shuffle=False)
    return model

model = train_model(get_model(), X_train, Y_train, (X_dev, Y_dev), [plot_losses])
```

**DataSet:** [Bike sharing dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Bike+Sharing+Dataset)

**Desired Exit**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a slight variation of your script in Google Colab, directly loading the zip from the web and processing it (code included below) and I don't get any errors.  Not entirely sure what is different, but this version might be useful - perhaps the input data to your fitting process was not being read correctly from local csv - I hope this helps:

```
# Source for download_extract_zip: 
# https://techoverflow.net/2018/01/16/downloading-reading-a-zip-file-in-memory-using-python/
from zipfile import ZipFile
import requests
import io
import zipfile
def download_extract_zip(url):
    """
    Download a ZIP file and extract its contents in memory
    yields (filename, file-like object) pairs
    """
    response = requests.get(url)
    with zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response.content)) as thezip:
        for zipinfo in thezip.infolist():
            with thezip.open(zipinfo) as thefile:
                yield zipinfo.filename, thefile

import pandas as pd

def load_dataset():
    ds=''
    raw_dataset = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00275/Bike-Sharing-Dataset.zip'
    for (iFilename, iFile) in download_extract_zip(raw_dataset):
        if iFilename == 'hour.csv':
            ds = pd.read_csv(iFile)
            ds['dteday'] = pd.to_datetime(ds['dteday'])
    return ds

def one_hot_encoding(df, field):
    one_hot_encoded = pd.get_dummies(df[field])
    return  pd.concat([df.drop(field, axis=1), one_hot_encoded], axis=1)

def preprocess_dataset(df):

    df_reduced = df[['dteday', 'cnt', 'season','yr', 'mnth','hr', 'holiday', 'weekday', 'workingday', 'weathersit', 'temp', 'atemp', 'hum', 'windspeed']]
    df_reduced = one_hot_encoding(df_reduced, 'season')
    df_reduced = one_hot_encoding(df_reduced, 'mnth')
    df_reduced = one_hot_encoding(df_reduced, 'hr')
    df_reduced = one_hot_encoding(df_reduced, 'weekday')
    df_reduced = one_hot_encoding(df_reduced, 'weathersit')

    return df_reduced

dataset = load_dataset()
dataset = preprocess_dataset(dataset)

from datetime import datetime

def filter_by_date(ds, start_date, end_date):

    start_date_parsed = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d") 
    start_end_parsed = datetime.strptime(end_date, "%Y-%m-%d")

    return ds[(ds['dteday'] >= start_date_parsed) & (ds['dteday'] <= start_end_parsed)]

train = filter_by_date(dataset, '2011-01-01', '2012-10-31')
dev = filter_by_date(dataset, '2012-11-01', '2012-11-30')
val = filter_by_date(dataset, '2012-12-01', '2012-12-31')

import numpy as np

def reshape_dataset(ds):

    Y = ds['cnt'].values

    ds_values = ds.drop(['dteday', 'cnt'], axis=1).values
    X = np.reshape(ds_values, (ds_values.shape[0], 1, ds_values.shape[1]))

    return X, Y

X_train, Y_train = reshape_dataset(train)
X_dev, Y_dev = reshape_dataset(dev)
X_val, Y_val = reshape_dataset(val)

import keras
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import clear_output

class PlotLosses(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.i = 0
        self.x = []
        self.losses = []
        self.val_losses = []

        self.fig = plt.figure()        
        self.logs = []

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):

        self.logs.append(logs)
        self.x.append(self.i)
        self.losses.append(logs.get('loss'))
        self.val_losses.append(logs.get('val_loss'))
        self.i += 1

        clear_output(wait=True)
        plt.plot(self.x, self.losses, label="loss")
        plt.plot(self.x, self.val_losses, label="val_loss")
        plt.legend()
        plt.show()

plot_losses = PlotLosses()

from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, LSTM, Dropout

def get_model():

    input = Input(shape=(1, 58))
    x = LSTM(200)(input)
    x = Dropout(.5)(x)
    activation = Dense(1, activation='linear')(x)
    model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=activation)

    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01,
                                      beta_1=0.9,
                                      beta_2=0.999,
                                      epsilon=None,
                                      decay=0.001,
                                      amsgrad=False)

    model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer=optimizer)
    model.summary()

    return model

get_model()

def train_model(model, X_train, Y_train, validation, callbacks):

    model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=200, batch_size=1024, validation_data=validation, callbacks=callbacks, shuffle=False)
    return model

model = train_model(get_model(), X_train, Y_train, (X_dev, Y_dev), [plot_losses])
```